# Protractor testing angular ng-options

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-jquery, angularjs-ng-options

I four `<select>` with `ng-options` used in my page that will retrieve different information.
All of them are like this, except with different data binding, names and ids:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <label class="control-label" for="lawyer">Lawyer</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="lawyer" name="lawyer" ng-model="model.lawyerUuid" required
      ng-options="lawyer.uuid as lawyer.name for lawyer in model.lawyers">
   </select>
</div>
```

How can I test this in protractor so I can make sure there are only x (e.g. 2) lawyers returned ?

Since I use `ng-options`, finding by `ng-repeat` won't work and if I search with the following, I will get all four `<selects>` in my page and not only the one above (so if all of them would return 2 elements I would have a `count()` of 8):

```
element.all(by.css('select option'))
```

Is there a way to retrieve all the elements that have a parent with some specified id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.findElements(protractor.By.css('#lawyer > option')).then(function (lawyers) {
    expect(lawyers.length).toBe(2);
});
```

This is similar to finding it by repeat but may still work

Comment: This won't work since it will only retrieve the parent(e.g. the lawyer `select`) but not it's children (i.e. `option`).

Comment: possibly finding it by css then? Something like css('#lawyer > option')

Answer (score 0):

So I found this solution by tinkering with xpath:

```
expect(element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="lawyer"]/child::node()')).count()).toBe(2);
```

Is there a nice one ?